# Function definition, C to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll

I have some C code which I have converted into a DLL. I need to call the DLL from a C# program. I'm getting the error *"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."*

So, I believe that I haven't converted my function prototype right which is leading to memory leaks.

The function prototype in C is

```
int __stdcall karacell_bridge( int argumentCount, char **argContent)
```

Is this a correct conversion of the function prototype in C# DLL call?

```
[DllImport("KaracellLib.dll", EntryPoint = "karacell_bridge@8", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int karacell_bridge(int argumentCount, [In, Out]string[] argContent);
```

Comment: We need to know more about how the DLL is compiled. Why do you assume it is `StdCall`?

Comment: I use the following statements to compile the C code into a DLL, 
For .dll, .def, .a file creation
gcc -shared -o KaracellLib.dll karacell.obj -DDEBUG jytter.obj -W1,--output-def,karacellLib.def,--out-implib,libkaracell.a

Removing mangling of function names
gcc -shared -o KaracellLib.dll karacell.obj -DDEBUG jytter.obj -W1,--kill-at

Comment: I had a reason why I added StdCall, but not able to recollect it now. But even if I remove that bit and run the program again, the same error is thrown.

Comment: What error is thrown? And what makes you think there's a memory leak? And removing `StdCall` doesn't do anything, since that's the default. Try it with `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: The error thrown is "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." I eliminated a lot of possibilities for the occurrence of this error. I was unsure if my function prototype was right.

Comment: If I change it to cdecl, then I get this error A call to PInvoke function 'karacell_bridge' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.""

Comment: Please note, I have made a modification in the C function definition. The previous one was mangled somehow by the text editor!

Comment: Are you sure it's safe to assume that an `[In, Out] string[] argContent` matches to a `char **argContent`? I'd expect that a `char **argContent` might match to a `char **argContent`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd need to marshal the second argument. I'm not sure if there's a safe PInvoke way to marshal modifiable arrays of strings; It seems like there would be many failure modes here. Perhaps you could try converting the array of strings to an array of `char *`.

Comment: I could give that a try. Any idea how I can initialize a char * str[] data type in C#?
Also, how do I dereference and assign values? I'm kind of unclear about C# pointers..

Comment: Changed the C function prototype to (int, char[], char[], char[], char[], char[]). And modified the C# one to the same signature. Still same error! I hate DLLs!

Comment: Have you worked out how to Marshal strings as `char[]`? For your most recent attempt to work, you'll need that.

Comment: I don't use string at all. I just converted both the function prototypes to char[].

Comment: Have you worked out how to marshal correctly? I shouldn't have to ask questions twice!

Comment: I'll assume the answer is "no". Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor5

Comment: I meant there wasn't a need to Marshal strings as char[] as I did not use strings in both the managed and unmanaged code. Thanks for the link anyway!